# Is it possible to automate installate wordpress with wp-cli?

Tags: php, wordpress, wp-cli

Is it possible to go through this sites without clicking but with shell commands (i mean wp-cli):
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to that question is yes.

```sh
# Create a config file.
wp config create --dbname="my_db" --dbuser="my_db_user" --dbpass="my_db_pass" --dbhost="127.0.0.1"
# Install WordPress.
wp core install --url="blog.localhost/blog" --title="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" --admin_user="admin" --admin_password="admin" --admin_email="admin@example.com" --skip-email
# Install a different language.
wp language core install de_DE
```